# Как правильно составить SQL запрос?

Tags: mysql, sql

Всем привет. Прошу прощения за такой вопрос, но я не знаю как его по другому сформулировать.
Буду краток. Для примера, есть 2 таблицы.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как мне добавить строчку в таблицу order если я знаю только **имя** покупателя и **цену.**(Получается я знаю *Name из таблицы byer* и *Price*)
Пользуюсь я *mysql connector/Python* Я попробовал вложенный запрос. Но у меня это не заработало. Да и мне кажется что вложенный запрос для такой простой задачи не правильно.

Comment: Разве он вложенный. `insert into order(ByerId,Price) select id,? from byer where Name=?`. Вместо вопросов подставляются ваши переменные (в питоне вроде именно `?` используются ...

Comment: @Mike название таблицы `order` экранировать не надо (как ключевое слово)?

Comment: Да, надо, обратными апосторфами. просто тут в комментариях они для выделения используются писать не стал

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как то так:

```
query="insert into `order`(ByerId,Price) select id,%s from byer where Name=%s"
cursor.execute(query, (Price,Name))
```